# Can't create an User on AWS IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm trying to setup my aws cli. I downloaded it and everything worked.
Now I wanted to log in from my powershell script.

`Set-AWSCredentials –AccessKey key-name –SecretKey key-name`

Because I don't have any users at the moment I had to create one. I have given the user admin rights.

When creating the user aws throws this error:

`User: arn:aws:sts::37197122623409:assumed-role/voclabs/user2135080=.... is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateUser on resource: arn:aws:iam::371237422423709:user/.... because no identity-based policy allows the iam:CreateUser action`

My first thought was that my education account is having a problem. But I didn't find anything about it. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Let you assume that the error message is precise and correct. Unless you put a random placeholder at the account place of the ARNs in the error message you are trying to create a user in a different account. 

    Requester: 37197122623409
    Resource:  371237422423709

The user has to have that permission in its IAM policy. Can you provide the part of the policy which you believe gives you the `iam:CreateUser` permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "voclab" part of the error suggests you are not logged as the account root user but instead assuming a role in an account used for teaching purposes.
This role is probably designed to disallow IAM actions, in order to prevent privilege  escalation.

Read
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtogetcredentials.html to get role credentials for the role you're assuming

Answer (score 1):

You can't make any IAM roles, policies or users as a student using `voclabs` account. AWS Academy does not allow to do that and its a **hard limit** which you nor your educator can change.

Answer (score 0):

Use an existing role called: `LabRole`,
if you are using `AWS Learner Lab`, because you are not allowed to create a new role.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).